# Chrome Interactive session is opening black page

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Hi I was using selenium chrome drivers as interactive service to open some websites. It was working fine. Suddenly found that the session is not loading correctly and showing black page. Found following error:

**chrome automation extension has crashed. click this balloon to reload the extension**

Answer (score 0):

Found that with chrome browser version was updated to v51 and selenium-chromedriver 2.21 is compatible with v50.
Downgraded chrome browser to v50. Now it is working fine.

Comment: ChromeDriver v2.21 (2016-01-28)
Supports Chrome v46-50

Comment: Found  ChromeDriver v2.22  is released on 2016-06-06 which supports
Chrome v49-52.

Comment: Need to test v2.22 in interactive session services.